# How can I securely store/use Spotify access tokens in the case where multiple user's login and use my website at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, spotify

I am working on a side project as a learning experience. I'm trying to create a web app where any user can login and authenticate with Spotify so I can make API calls and display some data. I've read through the docs and some examples and want to use auth code or auth code w/ PKCE but I'm not quite sure I understand how the access tokens work.

If I were to keep the access token in a variable and use it to perform API calls on my server, I'm sure that will lead to many problems when more than 1 user authenticates at once. It will replace the access token and I'm not sure how to deal with that in a secure manner.
I've thought about some solutions, but not sure which is best, or if I am even understanding how everything works.

1. From reading through the [example code](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-examples/blob/master/authentication/authorization_code/app.js) and Spotify Auth [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow), it seems the example is redirecting with a hash to pass the tokens and be able to retrieve them from the URL.

```
// we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
res.redirect('/#' +
  querystring.stringify({
    access_token: access_token,
    refresh_token: refresh_token
  }));
```

I assume this is used as a way to make sure API calls will use each user's unique token. Isn't this bad in terms of security though because each user's token can get exposed?

2. I've also seen some spotify projects on github using cookies or localstorage to store each user's tokens separately, then retrieve them when making the API calls. This seems like a simple solution and one I want to go with, but shouldn't you be concerned about the security with XSS attacks or similar? Or would it be okay in this use case because the access tokens do end up expiring and even if the access tokens were to get intercepted, you can't do anything too malicious.
3. Database to store access tokens. I think this is the most secure but I want to avoid using a database just to store expiring tokens if possible.

Is my understanding of how the access tokens are supposed to be used when dealing with multiple concurrent users correct? Are there other simple solutions? I'm thinking about basing my authentication code to be similar to the Spotify example linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your work is using HTTPS every step of the way, all of this is, by and large, fine.

HTTPS encrypts basically everything. The message body, headers, and query string. However, it's not advised in general to put tokens in the query string as the server often logs that string. See [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39017138/16658130)

As for storage of the token, it depends what you're trying to do. Don't forget, if you're trying to make requests from your server to Spotify, you're likely to run into issues with CORS.

If you are doing work from server to Spotify, your options are essentially:

1. Store the user's Spotify tokens in a database against your own users.
2. Store the user's Spotify tokens clientside, then have them send them to you for every request you need to make.

Storing in cookies shouldn't be a problem though someone might yell at me for that. ASP.NET does this for auth out of the box.

As for XSS, this depends; are you planning on having potentially XSS vulnerable stuff on your site? Ultimately, it is your job to secure against that, and it depends if you're even exposed to it. Go read a little about how they work.

Unless you've got say, a comment section or other way for users to "share" data between them, you're probably fine. If you do have something like that, there are relatively trivial techniques to sanitize inputs and renders to secure yourself.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That helped me understand some stuff and I was able to do some more research.
I'm currently using express and making requests with axios. All my javascript code is server side, so if I stored tokens in cookies (res.cookie) and retrieved them whenever requests are needed, I wouldn't run into CORS issues because my server is making the requests right? Would this still be problematic since I am not using client-side javascript? I also assume I don't need session identifiers if I just want to store tokens to use for API reqs. Sorry, I haven't had much experience with this.

Comment: Something like this w/ HTTPS would be secure I hope?: `res.cookie('access_token', response.data.access_token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'strict' });`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say for sure if anything you're doing is secure. One line isn't enough, security is a system-wide consideration. I will say though that CORS is actually a problem when querying out from your server, and not from your client, typically.